# Catastrophic loss of precision

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to solve a double integral in the range of 0 to Infinity (for both the integrals) and *Mathematica* is giving me the following error:

> Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral

Here is my code:

```
z = 2 + x + y;
s = 0.5;
m2 = 5325;
m1 = 5279;
mz = 10605.5;

NIntegrate[
 1/z^3 (x + y + 2 x y) (1 + s^2/(2 m2^2 z)) Exp[-(m2^2 x + m1^2 y)/
    s^2 + (mz^2 (x + y + 2 x y))/(2 s^2 z)], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, 
  Infinity}]
```

What does this error message mean, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: The accumulation of error in the arithmetic of approximate `Real` numbers can sometimes get so great that a result loses all significance.  To overcome, increase `WorkingPrecision` or post the actual problem and see if someone can help.

Comment: I am trying to solve

for
l = 2 + x + y;
s = 0.5;
m2 = 5325;
m1 = 5279;
mz = 10605.5;
abc = NIntegrate[
  1/l^3 (x + y + 2 x y) (1 + s^2/(2 m2^2 l)) Exp[-(m2^2 x + m1^2 y)/
     s^2 + (mz^2 (x + y + 2 x y))/(2 s^2 l)], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0,
    Infinity}]

Comment: Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: I have edited and I am using Mathematica 10

Comment: Please change the letter `l` to something else, say `L0`. I can figure if I am looking at a 1 or l in your code, they look very much the same.

Comment: z = 2 + x + y;
s = 0.5;
m2 = 5325;
m1 = 5279;
mz = 10605.5;

NIntegrate[
 1/z^3 (x + y + 2 x y) (1 + s^2/(2 m2^2 z)) Exp[-(m2^2 x + m1^2 y)/
    s^2 + (mz^2 (x + y + 2 x y))/(2 s^2 z)], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, 
  Infinity}]

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that your integrand is just too large numerically to be handled correctly. Are you sure the expressions you are using are based on sound model or mathematics? The number they generate are so large. I can't imagine real physical problem will produce such values.

Trying just integrating over `x` by fixing `y` to see the problem. I went only to `y=10`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
makeIntegrand[y_] := (
   z = 2 + x + y;
   s = 1/2;
   m2 = 5325;
   m1 = 5279;
   mz = 106055/10;
   b = x + y + 2 x y;
   1/z^3 b (1 + s^2/(2 m2^2 z)) Exp[(-m2^2 x + m1^2 y)/s^2 + (mz^2  b)/(2 s^2 z)]
   );

r = Table[{i, NIntegrate[makeIntegrand[i], {x, 0, Infinity}]}, {i, 0, 10, 1}];
r = Insert[r, {"y", "Integrate[...,{x,0,Infinity}]"}, 1];
Grid[r, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for responding. Actually I was trying to do mathematical analysis, but I think I am missing something. let me understand the problem again and then I will come back you. Thank you

Comment: the problem is solved, actually the value of factor "s" is 500 not 0.5.